# /etc/fstab is mounted too late, causing some daemon fail

Tags: systemd, boot, fstab, automounting

I wrote some entries in `/etc/fstab`, for example mounting on `/tmp`.

It seems systemd mounts `/etc/fstab` entries too late, after some daemon already started, for example Xorg.

Xorg creates `.X11-unix` in `/tmp`, then systemd mounts on `/tmp`, so files already in `/tmp` disappear. That causes some programs can't talk to X.

How to make `/etc/fstab` entries mounted early? Or should I use something other than `/etc/fstab`?

Answer (score 1):

This suggests the unit file that starts Xorg has insufficient dependencies, and so `systemd` ends up running it too early.

At least in Debian, local filesystem mounts automatically have ordering dependency `Before=local-fs.target`, and the `local-fs.target` is wanted by `sysinit.target` which is responsible for early system initialization, so all the local filesystems should be mounted when `sysinit.target` is done.

And unless the unit that starts Xorg has `DefaultDependencies=no` it will implicitly have both `Requires=sysinit.target` and `After=sysinit.target`, so it should start only after `sysinit.target` is done. Only units responsible for low-level system initialization should have `DefaultDependencies=no`.

However, if your `/tmp` is a remote filesystem, you might need to add a `After=remote-fs.target` dependency to the unit that starts Xorg. The easiest way to do this is to use `systemctl edit` to edit it, causing `systemctl` to automatically create a drop-in file with your changes (only) in `/etc/systemd/system/<name of the Xorg-starting unit>.d/`.

You should indicate the name and version of your Linux distribution, so that if that particular version has some specific quirks in its `systemd` configuration, someone who's aware of those quirks might give you a more focused answer.